# Upgrade cakephp 2.6 to 2.8 to work php 7

Tags: php, cakephp, php-7, cakephp-2.6, cakephp-2.8

I have a cakephp website on 2.6 and want to run it on php 7. Will it work if I upgrade cakephp to 2.8?

I have shared server therefore I cannot have php 5.*.

Answer (score 2):

#### Requirements

Here are the [Requirements](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#requirements) for running **CakePHP 2.x**

As longs as you have those you should be fine.

#### Migration Guide 2.6 -> 2.8

More about [PHP7 Compatibility](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-8-migration-guide.html#php7-compatibility)

And make sure you read this migration guide here

- [2.7](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-7-migration-guide.html)
- [2.8](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-8-migration-guide.html)

There are no breaking changes, but still worth a read.

Comment: Also learn about [**testing**](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html). Your application should be properly covered by tests so that you can easily  check for possible problems after making changes, being it an upgrade, adding functionality, fixing bugs, etc...

Comment: Migration guides are basically a change log and **not** a guide for steps to take to perform an actual migration. Good luck finding those steps. It seems every CakePHP dev makes the assumption you magically have this knowledge.